# Getting weekly reach demographics in Facebook Insights?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

What's the metric for reach demographics in Facebook Insights APis? I mean the same as **page_fans_gender_age** but for reach:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request "Insights" for your page without specifying a specific metric:

https://graph.facebook.com/your_page_id/insights/?token=...

This will provide you with a list of all available Insights for the page. You will find the answer you are looking for in there. It's not currently listed in the documentation for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think Facebook use "Page Impressions" for the API and "Reach" for the end user:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#page_impressions

The one that might help you is "page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique" or "page_impressions_unique" if the gender isn't important.

Answer (score -1):

It seems they're nowhere to be found unfortunately.